# Discord.JS v14 Slash Command - Western Stand Off

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So my problem is when I click the reaction, the message won't edit? I've checked the docs and all, but it still just won't work, I've got to be doing something wrong. Anyone able to help?

I've tried just about everything, and no one I know seems to have an idea on what the problem is either. here's the script:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, Events, Embed, } = require('discord.js')
const chalk = require('chalk');
const wait = require('node:timers/promises').setTimeout;

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('standoff')
        .setDescription(`Have a western standoff with another user.`)
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option.setName('user')
                .setDescription(`Who do you want to have a standoff with?`)
                .setRequired(true)),

    async execute (interaction) {

            const { client } = interaction;

            const target = interaction.options.getUser('user');
            const intUser = interaction.user

            let today = new Date();
            let date = today.getMonth()+1+`/`+today.getDate()+`/`+today.getFullYear();
            let logTime = today.getHours() + `:` + today.getMinutes() 
            let dateTime = date+' '+logTime;


        const standoffErrorEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            standoffErrorEmbed.setTitle(`STANDOFF`)
            standoffErrorEmbed.setColor(`Red`)

        if (target.bot) {
            standoffErrorEmbed.setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}>, you can't have a standoff against a bot.`)
            interaction.reply({ embeds: [standoffErrorEmbed] })
            console.log(chalk.white(`${dateTime} │ `,chalk.green(`${interaction.user.tag} in ${interaction.guild.name} tried using /standoff on a bot.`)));
            return;
        } else if (target.id === interaction.user.id) {
            standoffErrorEmbed.setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}>, you can't have a standoff with yourself.`)
            interaction.reply({ embeds: [standoffErrorEmbed] })
            console.log(chalk.white(`${dateTime} │ `,chalk.green(`${interaction.user.tag} in ${interaction.guild.name} tried using /standoff on themself.`)));
            return;
        } else if (!target || target === null) {
            standoffErrorEmbed.setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}>, you need to select a valid opponent`)
            interaction.reply({ embeds: [standoffErrorEmbed] })
            console.log(chalk.white(`${dateTime} │ `,chalk.green(`${interaction.user.tag} in ${interaction.guild.name} tried using /standoff on an invalid user.`)));
            return;
        } else {

            const standoffEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                standoffEmbed.setTitle(`STANDOFF`)
                standoffEmbed.setColor('Yellow')
                standoffEmbed.setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/762927301108695141/1137185724286902272/R.png')
                standoffEmbed.setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}> challenged <@${target.id}> to a standoff! \nThe first person to click the <:revolver_left:1137134967697182741> when it appears will win!`)

            const shootTimeList = [4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000]

            const shootTime = shootTimeList[Math.floor(Math.random() * shootTimeList.length)]

            let standoffMessage = `<:revolver_left:1137134967697182741>       <:revolver_right:1137134969374900275>`

            const standoffEmbedShot = await interaction.reply({ content: `${standoffMessage}`, embeds: [standoffEmbed], fetchReply: true })

            const collectorFilter = (reaction, user) => {
                return reaction.emoji.id === '<:revolver_left:1137134967697182741>' && user.id === interaction.user.id || user.id === target.id;
            };

            const collector = standoffEmbedShot.createReactionCollector({ filter: collectorFilter, time: shootTime + 15000 });
            
            wait(shootTime);
            standoffEmbedShot.react('<:revolver_left:1137134967697182741>')
            collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {

                if (user.id === interaction.user.id && reaction.emoji.id === `<:revolver_left:1137134967697182741>`) {
                    standoffEmbedShot.reactions.removeAll()
                    standoffMessage = `<:revolver_left:1137134967697182741>       <:revolver_right:1137134969374900275>`
                    standoffEmbed.setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}> won the standoff!`)
                    standoffEmbed.setColor('Green')
                    standoffEmbedShot.editReply({ content: `${standoffMessage}`, embeds: [standoffEmbed] })
                    console.log(chalk.white(`${dateTime} │ `,chalk.green(`${interaction.user.tag} in ${interaction.guild.name} used /standoff on ${target.tag}. The winner was ${interaction.user.tag}.`)));
                    return;
                } else if (user.id === target.id && reaction.emoji.id === `<:revolver_left:1137134967697182741>`) {
                    standoffEmbedShot.reactions.removeAll()
                    standoffMessage = `<:revolver_left:1137134967697182741>       <:revolver_right:1137134969374900275>`
                    standoffEmbed.setDescription(`<@${target.id}> won the standoff!`)
                    standoffEmbed.setColor('Green')
                    standoffEmbedShot.editReply({ content: `${standoffMessage}`, embeds: [standoffEmbed] })
                    console.log(chalk.white(`${dateTime} │ `,chalk.green(`${interaction.user.tag} in ${interaction.guild.name} used /standoff on ${target.tag}. The winner was ${target.tag}.`)));
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `'<:revolver_left:1137134967697182741>'` is not an ID. You should check if `reaction.emoji.id === '1137134967697182741'` instead

Comment: That didn't work, i changed it to ``if (user.id === interaction.user.id && reaction.emoji.id === `1137134967697182741`) {`` and still having the same issue